# M equivalent for DAX poisson.dist

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery, m

does anyone know if there is an M equivalent for the poisson distribution formula in DAX ? I have a query where I want to calculate the formula based on 2 columns but can't find any solution anywhere. Or should i just add the query to the data model and use DAX to calculate it there ?

Comment: Maybe this youtube video will help - [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWva7msu8Yk). I know this is a bad practice on SO to simply paste a link to the solution, but I won't even pretend I understand what's going on there...!

Answer (score 1):

You can define it based on the definition as a custom function.

Here's one example of how to implement `PoissonDist(k,mean,cdf)` using [`List.Accumulate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-accumulate) for the cumulative sum:

```
(k as number, mean as number, cdf as logical) as number =>
let
    k = Number.RoundDown(k, 0),
    Poisson = Number.Exp(-mean) * Number.Power(mean, k) / Number.Factorial(k),
    Cumulative = List.Accumulate(List.Range({0..k},0), 0, (state, current) => state + Number.Exp(-mean) * Number.Power(mean, current) / Number.Factorial(current)),
    Switch = if cdf then Cumulative else Poisson,
    Result = if k < 0 or mean < 0 then error "Input cannot be negative." else Switch
in
    Result
```

This version is a bit more compact but essentially the same thing:

```
(k as number, m as number, cdf as logical) as number =>
let
    k = if k > 0 and m > 0 then Number.RoundDown(k,0) else error "Input cannot be < 0.",
    Poisson = List.Accumulate(List.Range({0..k}, if cdf then 0 else k), 0,
        (sum, i) => sum + Number.Exp(-m) * Number.Power(m, i) / Number.Factorial(i))
in
    Poisson
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Alexis has some flaws that were relevant in my case:

1. `Poisson(0, 0, false)` throws an error caused by `Number.Power(0, 0)` in both versions. Excel in comparison returns the correct value `1` (see recursive definition at wikipedia).
2. Computing the cumulative value is expensive, so for better performance list operations should only be executed if really needed (first version).
3. Also performance: adding the expression `Number.Exp(-m)` can be extracted to outside of the list operation (second version).
4. Also performance: repeated computation of power and faculty can be replaced by iterated multiplications (second version).

So here is my version of the Poisson distribution:

```json
(x as number, mean as number, cumulative as logical) as number =>
    let
        k = if x >= 0 then  Number.RoundDown(x, 0) else error "x must not be negative",
        m = if mean >= 0 then mean else error "mean must not be negative",
        result = Number.Exp(-m) * (if k = 0 then 1 else List.Accumulate({1..k}, [sum = 1, element = 1], (state, i) => let next = state[element]*m/i in [sum = if cumulative then state[sum] + next else next, element = next])[sum])
    in
        result
```